# Convert function pointer type to corresponding string

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

Haven't read a book about C++ templates yet so I'm stuck on a problem. I'm using C++14.

How to convert function pointer type to particular string based on type itself?
I have function pointer types:

```
    using FuncType1 = int (*)(double);
    using FuncType2 = int (*)(int);
    using FuncType3 = int (*)(int);
```

I would like to write something like this:

```
class Test {
private:
   template<FuncType1> static const std::string func_name = "FuncType1";
   template<FuncType2> static const std::string func_name = "FuncType2";
   template<FuncType3> static const std::string func_name = "FuncType3";
public:
   template<T> std::string GetFuncType() {
      return func_name<T>::value;
   }
};
```

I know this doesn't compile but should be enough to show idea. I think it's possible to specialize `GetFuncType` method but I would prefer to specialize member variable `func_name` instead (if that's even possible). Also - would FuncType2 and FuncType3 resolve to correct string if code is fixed?

Comment: There is no way to distinguish between FuncType2 and FuncType3. They are the same type.

Comment: `template<FuncType1>` that won't compile, you cannot specialize aliases.

Comment: Ok, what if we assume that aliases in Test declaration are replaced with function pointer type?

Comment: You may be able to use a [stack trace](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/programmatic-access-to-the-call-stack-in-c/) to get the information you need, although this might require a pdb depending on your platform/compiler. Just a thought for you though, just in case it might be what you need.

Comment: I get what you mean but no this time it's more about how to map function pointer type to some other value.

Comment: @jozols That makes sense. I wasn't 100% sue that's what you were looking for, but I figured I'd mention it just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would prefer to specialize member variable func_name instead (if that's even possible).

So, if I understand correctly, you're looking something as

```
class Test
 {
   private:
      template <typename> static const std::string func_name;

   public:
      template <typename T> 
      std::string GetFuncType () const
       { return func_name<T>; }
 };

template <typename> const std::string Test::func_name = "not func";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType1> = "FuncType1";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType2> = "FuncType2";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType3> = "FuncType3";
```

given that `FuncType1`, `FuncType2` and `FuncType3` are different types (not equals as `FuncType2` and `FuncType3` in you question).

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using FuncType1 = int (*)(double);
using FuncType2 = int (*)(int);
using FuncType3 = int (*)(long);

class Test
 {
   private:
      template <typename> static const std::string func_name;

   public:
      template <typename T> 
      std::string GetFuncType () const
       { return func_name<T>; }
 };

template <typename> const std::string Test::func_name = "not func";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType1> = "FuncType1";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType2> = "FuncType2";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType3> = "FuncType3";

int main ()
 { 
   std::cout << Test{}.GetFuncType<int>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << Test{}.GetFuncType<FuncType1>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << Test{}.GetFuncType<FuncType2>() << std::endl;
   std::cout << Test{}.GetFuncType<FuncType3>() << std::endl;
 }
```

If you want that `Test{}.GetFuncType<int>()` gives a compilation error, you can initialize `func_name` only for requested specializations

```
// template <typename> const std::string Test::func_name = "not func";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType1> = "FuncType1";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType2> = "FuncType2";
template<> const std::string Test::func_name<FuncType3> = "FuncType3";

// ...

std::cout << Test{}.GetFuncType<int>() << std::endl; // compilation error!
```

Comment: Oops, you're right. (Deleted incorrect comment about C++14 not having variable templates.)

Comment: Thanks, this is how I imagined it would work but struggled to get syntax right. Basically you have to declare template in class and specialize outside when defining members. Can't initialize members inside class declaration because I use "complex" type like string.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
template<class T> constexpr char const* get_name() = delete;

using FuncType1 = int (*)(double);
using FuncType2 = int (*)(int);

template<> constexpr char const* get_name<FuncType1>() { return "FuncType1"; }
template<> constexpr char const* get_name<FuncType2>() { return "FuncType2"; }

int main() {
    std::cout << get_name<FuncType1>() << '\n';
    std::cout << get_name<FuncType2>() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Hmm,  nice - you actually specialized on aliases.

Comment: Is it possible to specialize non-method class member? For example member like this: `template<> constexpr char const* func_name<FuncType1> = "FuncType1";`